# perform data-toggle with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that toggles a bootstrap modal.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

I want to do the same thing with a jquery function. Is this possible?

Comment: I want to do data-toggle"modal" data-target"#myModal" with a jquery function.

Comment: have you read the doc from bootstrap site? if you did, you should notice it can be triggered in javascript way    $('#myModal').modal('show')

Answer (score 28, accepted):

give your button id and hide it:

**CSS:**

```
#btnTrigger
{
display:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="btnTrigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

and on someother event or condition just click it programmatically:

**JQuery:**

```
$('#btnTrigger').click();
```

In Result, popup will be displayed.

Answer (score 25):

With simple code like you posted:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

It won't show modal dialog unless you write code in javascript like:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $($(this).attr("data-target")).modal("show");
});
```

And what you will put in `data-target` will open a div with id as dialog modal.

or

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $($(this).data("target")).modal("show");
});
```

Comment: Is user's choice, not mine :)

Comment: Definitely the better answer, since it answers the question as opposed to giving a work around.. Oh well, I found it very helpful!

Answer (score 8):

below code worked for me, you can call this function on any event

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ShowModel = function () {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have no idea why *this* is not the answer

Answer (score 4):

Just a simple `$("#myModal").modal()` in any function of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read [this explanation](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/html5_data-_attributes_are_great_and_you_know_it.html) about the "data-" html5 attribute.

You can define custom data- attributes and use them when developing your plugins.

This is what bootstrap did.

If you want to use it in JQuery to show a modal dialog - you should write a plugin similar to what bootstrap did.

I suggest you read bootstrap's source code and see how they used this attribute.